# Not sure if i installed the nvidia drivers for ubuntu correctly

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, wine

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu and heard that there was a problem with the drivers being offered by the system, so i downloaded the latest from the nvidia website. I installed them by first removing nuveau then stopped x server and installed them. I just installed EVE Online thru wine and it shows 8300 GS1 as a graphics card (i have a 8500gt)

Is this just a visual bug or are the drivers not installed corectly?

Comment: Can you check a GPU diagnostic tool instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `nvidia-settings`; it should show what version your driver and X server are, the model of your monitor, and a whole lot besides.  If `nvidia-settings` shows your card correctly, then it is probably just an oddity with WINE.